# Can I apply for Canadian provincial nomination programs on my own with my express entry profile?

Tags: canada, resident-permit, skilled-migration, express-entry

I have an express entry profile. Is it possible for me to apply for any of the PNPs without waiting to get an invite from them? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it has helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes of-course. You can and you should.

The Provincial Nomination process ends with an express entry profile. When you get a  nomination letter from a province, you should create an EE profile and upload the letter there and persue the rest of the process from federal channel.

PN gives you 600 points in EE and you will get selected from EE pool at the next draw.
Check this [link](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/express-entry/eligibility/criteria-comprehensive-ranking-system.html) which explains how much point you might get with a PN.

Comment: But in the application for the nomination, will I need a job offer? Can I apply on my own for a nomination without a job offer? I couldn't find much info about this on the internet :(

Comment: @mayooran Well this is another question. I suggest you to post a new question so I would be able to answer it there. Anyway, you are right, most of PNPs need a valid job offer such as British Columbia but Saskatchewan, on the other hand does not need a job offer for its OID program.